# How can I display a text value for radio buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building an online store where the customer can select custom parts.
I'm quite new to javascript, but I've managed to create a radio button list, where the price is added from each section.

I would like a box to show all of the options selected, not just the sum total.

I've included the text with value and used parseInt. Is there an equivalent I can use to pull the text, not the number, from the value?

My code so far:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisplayPrice(price){
                        var val1 = 0;
                        for( i = 0; i < document.form1.part.length; i++ ){
                                if( document.form1.part[i].checked == true ){
                                        val1 = document.form1.part[i].value;
                                }
                        }

                        var val2 = 0;
                        for( i = 0; i < document.form2.part2.length; i++ ){
                                if( document.form2.part2[i].checked == true ){
                                        val2 = document.form2.part2[i].value;
                                }
                        }

        var val3 = 0;
                        for( i = 0; i < document.form3.part3.length; i++ ){
                                if( document.form3.part3[i].checked == true ){
                                        val3 = document.form3.part3[i].value;
                                }
                        }


                        var sum=parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2) + parseInt(val3);
            document.getElementById('totalSum').value=sum;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" runat="server">
       <br>
       <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="0 1.8ghz2xAMD" name="part" checked="checked" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">1.8Ghz Dual Core AMD
        <br>
        <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="50 2ghz2xAMD" name="part" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">2Ghz Dual Core AMD
        <br>
    </form>Choose your memory:<br />
    <form name="form2" id="form2" runat="server">
        <br>
        <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="0 1333corsair1gb" name="part2" checked="checked" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">1333 Corsair 1GB
        <br>
        <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="50 1333corsair2x1gb" name="part2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">1333 Corsair 2x1GB
        <br>
    </form>Choose your graphics card:<br />
    <form name="form3" id="form3" runat="server">
        <br />
        <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="0 5830ATI1gb" name="part3" checked="checked" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">1GB ATI 5830
        <br />
        <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="50 5850ATI1gb" name="part3" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">1GB ATI 5850
        <br />
        <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="75 5870ATI1gb" name="part3" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">1GB ATI 5870
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

The values seem to be consistently separated by a space. So you could use `split()` function to split the value in two parts, the first part containing the price and the second part containing the text.

```
var parts = value.split(" ");
var price = parseInt(parts[0]);
var text = parts[1];
```

That said, there are better/nicer ways to achieve the functional requirement, but that's up  to you to as an learning exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just seeing if I can get that to work, and also with a second numerical value. Much appreciated